# Xdocument getting element node value from another note in the xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to get some data from an XML file - see below.

Basically for each session data, I get all the elements in it and store it but I need to get the movie_Name from the  elements with reference by the movie.

```
<Schedule_Data>
    <Movies>
        <Movie>
            <Cinema_ID>3169101</Cinema_ID>
            <Movie_ID>1012689</Movie_ID>
            <Movie_Name>2D Captain America: Civil War</Movie_Name>
            <Rating>PG13</Rating>
            <Runtime>160</Runtime>
        </Movie>
        <Movie>
            <Cinema_ID>3169101</Cinema_ID>
            <Movie_ID>1012984</Movie_ID>
            <Movie_Name>2D Zootopia</Movie_Name>
            <Rating>PG</Rating>
            <Runtime>115</Runtime>
        </Movie>
    </Movies>
    <Sessions>
        <Session>
            <Cinema_ID>8888888</Cinema_ID>
            <Movie_ID>1012689</Movie_ID>
            <Session_ID>1083592422</Session_ID>
            <Price_group_code>10007</Price_group_code>
            <Auditorium_Number>9</Auditorium_Number>
            <Assigned_Seating>True</Assigned_Seating>
            <Attribute></Attribute>
            <Date_time>20160607141000</Date_time>
            <Total_Seats>87</Total_Seats>
            <Available_Seats>87</Available_Seats>
        </Session>
        <Session>
            <Cinema_ID>8888888</Cinema_ID>
            <Movie_ID>1012984</Movie_ID>
            <Session_ID>1083592423</Session_ID>
            <Price_group_code>10007</Price_group_code>
            <Auditorium_Number>9</Auditorium_Number>
        </Session>
    </Sessions>
</Schedule_Data>
```

Currently my code is:

```
XDocument thisXML = XDocument.Parse(responseText);

//get the dates element (which contains all the date nodes)
XElement datesElement = thisXML.Element("Schedule_Data").Element("Sessions");

//use linq to compile an ienumerable of the date nodes
var dates = from dateNode in datesElement.Elements("Session")
select dateNode;

//get the dates element (which contains all the film nodes)
XElement MoviesElement = thisXML.Element("Schedule_Data").Element("Movies");

foreach (XElement session in dates)
{
    //get movie name
    var films = from filmnode in MoviesElement.Elements("Movie")
    select filmnode;

    var movieId = session.Element("Movie_ID").Value;

    // This is where i try do the where clause and try get the value but it returns null
    var answer = from reply in films
    where reply.Element("Movie_ID").Value == movieId
    select films.Elements("Movie_Name");

    //create a new session import record
    ORM.Sessionimportattemptimportedsession newSessionimportattemptimportedsession = new ORM.Sessionimportattemptimportedsession();

    //check data and set properties
    newSessionimportattemptimportedsession.MovieTitle = answer.ToString();
    newSessionimportattemptimportedsession.ScreenNumber = session.Element("Screen_bytNum").Value;
    .....
    numberOfSessions++; 
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You're just performing a join between sessions and movies.  Just do this:

```
var query =
    from s in doc.Descendants("Session")
    join m in doc.Descendants("Movie")
    on (string)s.Element("Movie_ID") equals (string)m.Element("Movie_ID")
    select new
    {
        MovieName = (string)m.Element("Movie_Name"),
        Session = s,
        Movie = m,
    };
```